# I have 2 Haarcascades that work but every other one I download does not

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier

The two working ones are haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml from 2017 and haarcascade_frontalface_dog.xml from 2019.

Python 3.8 64 Bit on Windows10 using opencv-python 4.4.0.42

Every other one I have tried from Github returns the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Duncan\Python\working face.py", line 11, in <module>
    faceCascadedog = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPathdog)
    SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set 
      >>>
```

I have ensured the files are in the correct place and the names are correct.

I am specifically looking for Haars of Full Body, Animals and Common household Objects if anyone could point me to a location or a reason they are not working please.

Answer (score 0):

Please check slashes and spaces in your paths.

Slashes and spaces give a lot of troubles for Windows users. Thanks to Bill Gates and Microsoft!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I have already checked path, spelling etc, I started my computer life as a DOS user 30 years ago:)

Answer (score 0):

I randomly I found a set of Haars that work. Well, it's the same set I tried before, but instead of right clicking on individual Haars and clicking `save target as`, I downloaded them all as a .zip file, and it worked! I have no idea why! I would guess it has to do with which version I downloaded or something. Still, after Haars of common household objects if anyone has any good ones:) Things like hoovers, shoes, sofa etc.